# Command line utility to see list of tasks, CPU usage, and memory usage

Tags: windows, command-line, performance-analysis, system-monitor

I want to log, every 10 minutes, list of all the apps in Windows that are running, the CPU usage, and memory usage.

I have many node.exe tasks, so I want to see the arguments of the task (for example: `node c:\myscript.js`)

I tried: `tasklist/?` but didn't find anything related to CPU usage.

I tried: `procexp/?` but didn't find any way to export the list to file (or show in a console)

I tried: `cprocess` (NirSoft), it can dump to file, and show CPU, but it does not give the arguments of the exe that ran.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this simply with a batch file, here's something I quickly wrote up,

```
@echo off
ECHO ***Date and Time***
set datetimef=%date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%__%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
echo %datetimef%
ECHO ***List Processes***
WMIC path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline
ECHO ***CPU-Usage***
wmic cpu get loadpercentage
ECHO ***Memory Usage***
systeminfo | findstr Memory
```

It's pretty simple, you can tweak it to fit your needs but this meets your requirements. I also see that you want this data exported to a file so you can, output the contents of the batch file like this, `batch.bat > Logs-%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.log`

Comment: Link is broken FYI

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use [Python](https://www.python.org/) and the lovely [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library which can gather just about all of the information that you can dream of:

For a process *on Windows* you can get:

- cpu_percent
- cpu_times
- io_counters
- memory_info
- memory_maps
- num_ctx_switches
- num_handles
- num_threads
- username
- full exe path
- cmdline
- parent
- status
- cwd
- io_counters
- *much more*
- *even more on Linux & OSX*

Some *Python 3.5+* code to do more or less what you are asking for to the console, *(the same can be done with earlier Pythons but not with the f-string)*:

```
import psutil
import time
import datetime

while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            pr = proc.as_dict()
            print(f'{pr["name"]}\t{pr["memory_percent"]}\t{pr["cpu_percent"]}\t{pr["num_threads"]}\t{" ".join(pr["cmdline"][1:]) if pr["cmdline"] else ""}')
        except (OSError, psutil.AccessDenied):
            print(pr.name(), 'ACCESS DENIED')
    print('\n*** Ctrl-C to Exit ***\n\n')
    time.sleep(600) # Sleep for 10 Mins
```

On my machine the output looks like:
[image]

You could simply pipe the output to a file or you could modify the code to output to a .csv file directly.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Flexible